# The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors(help)

Tags: php

```
<?php
// Checks if the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
// Checks if a file was uploaded without errors
if (isset($_FILES['photo']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
 && $_FILES ['photo'] ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo $_FILES['photo']['type'], "<br />";
    // Checks if the file is a JPG image
    if ($_FILES ['photo'] ['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $tmp_img = $_FILES ['photo'] ['tmp_name'];
        // Creates an image resource
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $tmp_img );
        // Tells the browser what type of file
        header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
        // Outputs the file to the browser
        imagejpeg ( $image, '', 90 );
        // Frees the memory used for the file
        imagedestroy ( $image );
    }
    else {
        echo "Uploaded file was not a JPG image.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No photo uploaded!";
}
} else {
// If the form was not submitted, displays the form HTML
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="photo">User Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload a Photo" />
</form>
<?php } // End else statement ?>
```

This code is from the book "PHP for Absolute Beginners(2009).pdf", but when I tested it, I got the following error in Firefox:

> The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: what is in test.php?

Comment: nothing but test.php

Comment: you send the file to test.php and unless you dont know the code of the script there is no way to find the error which comes from that script

Comment: Most likely PHP is printing an error message but you can't see it because the browser tries to display it as an image. To go around this, first comment the line `header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );` and the two lines after this. Then you might see the error message, which you can post here.

Comment: when i commented the line comment the line `header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );`  browser showed `Warning: imagejpeg(): Filename cannot be empty in /opt/lampp/htdocs/simple_blog/test.php on line 14`  and i added a space as its name,  I got `Warning: imagejpeg( ): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/simple_blog/test.php on line 14`..

Comment: In `imagejpeg` replace the `''` with `null` if you're wanting the data output.

Comment: Incidentally, that's specifically mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/imagejpeg).

Comment: It works!! Thank you all!! Especially Jon! I'm a beginner of php and I had searched it for few hours, but didn't get useful information about it.. I'm sorry asked a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `imagejpeg` is trying to write the image to a file with an empty path (the second parameter) instead of displaying it in the browser, so you need to set this parameter to "null" instead.

You need to change your code to this:

```
// Set second param to "null" to directly output the image
imagejpeg ( $image, null, 90 );
imagedestroy ( $image );
// Exit here so that the HTML below is not mixed with the image data:
die();
```